# Is there anyway to display a list of objects using thymeleaf without using a table?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My goal is to display a list of applications that I have, but to do so I would prefer to do it in a non table format view, so is there anyway of iterating through my objects using thymeleaf and displaying them outside of a table view?

The current view I am trying to replicate is as shown below:

[image]

Where the image name is stored in the object so it can be displayed by being pulled from that.

The HTML is like this currently:

```
<div class="works__item">
        <img class="works__photo" th:src="@{/images/services/EV Station Locator.jpg}" alt="">
        <form th:action="@{/admin/evcharging}" th:method="get">
        <div class="works__content">
            <div class="works__title">EV Station Locator</div>
            <div class="works__text">Find the nearest EV Charging Station closest to you</div>
            <button class="btn btn--red btn--long">Learn more</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="works__item">
        <img class="works__photo" th:src="@{/images/services/Green Energy.jpg}" alt="">
        <div class="works__content">
            <div class="works__title">Green Energy</div>
            <div class="works__text">Check out how we plan to make our city greener.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any way to do this or not?

Comment: You can put a `th:each` on any element you wish...

Comment: As @Metroids said, including `<th:block>`.